# Success callback getting fired twice of Media API Cordova 3.3 IOS

Tags: ios, media, audio-recording, cordova-3

I have developed cordova 3.3 based mobile app for android & ios platforms. I have created one page for audio recording where I have used Media Api of cordova.
Suppose I have started audio recording by calling media.startRecord() method and after some time I stopped the audio recording by calling media.stopRecord() method.

After stopping recording in success callback I have given alert showing Audio recorded successfully. In case of android it works fine, but in case of IOS when I click on back button or another button to navigate to another page the alert is displayed again.

i.e. Alert is getting displayed twice in case of IOS.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue when I implemented my plugin using Cordova 3.4. I later found I called the following method twice which caused the callbacks are called twice by accident. Please check whether you have also used the similar way to notify Javascript from Objective-C.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(functionNameAbc:) name:EVENT_NAME_ABC object:nil];
```